# MySQL Select Distinct one Column from Many

Tags: mysql

```
 INSERT INTO geo (city, country, latitude, longitude)
 SELECT ansiname, country_code, latitude, longitude
 FROM   geonames2
 WHERE country_code='HK';
```

The following statement works fine except the 'ansiname' column has duplicates in it.

Meaning there can be a few city names with the same name but different lat/long.

```
 HK Kowloon 25.6225     56.2225
 HK Kowloon 24.80388    56.19449
```

Is there a way to alter this query so it will only select (and therefore insert) one instance of each ansiname? Therefore dropping the second (with diff lat/long).

I updated the SELECT as follows unsuccessfully:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(ansiname), country_code, latitude, longitude
```

thx

Comment: Do u have a distinct ID column on this table? otherwise, this is going to be a very difficult question to answer

Comment: yes there is a distinct ID column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`GROUP BY` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to accomplish this:

```
INSERT INTO geo (city, country, latitude, longitude)
SELECT ansiname, country_code, MAX(latitude), MAX(longitude)
FROM geonames2
WHERE country_code='HK'
GROUP BY ansiname, country_code
```

NOTE: By default, MySql doesn't require you to put the latitude and longitude into an aggregate function (`MAX`) if it isn't listed in the `GROUP BY`, but this setting is configurable and can vary from server to server... so it is a good practice to include the aggregate functions to avoid any potential errors.

---

EDIT: The issue with my suggest approach above is that it splits the lat / long.  Since you have an ID column in your table, you could select a single `ID` for every `ansiname`, `country_code` combination, and then pull the results for that `ID`:

```
INSERT INTO geo (city, country, latitude, longitude)
SELECT ansiname, country_code, latitude, longitude
FROM geonames2
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT MAX(Id) 
    FROM geonames2
    WHERE country_code='HK' 
    GROUP BY ansiname, country_code)
```

Comment: thats not going to work because now u have a disconnect between the city/country and the lat/long

Comment: This is not a very good solution. If, for example, there is a city with coordinates `(25.0, 56.9)` and  `(25.8, 55.0)`, then the result would be the `(25.8, 56.9)`. A result not existing as a row in the `geonames2` table.

Comment: ... that could very well be **outside** the city limits for a city with a diagonal (or other irregular) shape.

Comment: @ypercube You're right.  I wasn't thinking about splitting the lat / long between different records in the table.  I updated the answer to fix this, but my solution looks a lot like Churk's earlier answer...

Comment: a `JOIN` would probably be faster than `IN (SELECT ...)`. But slow and correct is better than fast and furious (wrong).

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO geo (city, country, latitude, longitude)
SELECT ansiname, country_code, latitude, longitude
FROM geonames2
WHERE id IN (select id FROM table WHERE country_code='HK' GROUP BY geonames2, country_code )
```

The subselect should return you ID of the first instance of a name / country_code pair